# Open a Screen on receiving background data only notification when the app is in killed state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

In my code i am receiving firebase data only notification when my app is in killed state. I have to open my app and show a particular screen on receiving of the data only notification.

I want to build a screen just like whenever a user will book something then the seller will be  redirected to a particular screen even the screen is locked where he will accept or decline the order, along with a ringtone, just like when we receive a whatsapp call.

**=> "react-native-invoke-app" it works good but not working in android version > 7.0.0**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which navigation library are you using ?

Comment: @HarishJangra I'm using react-navigation v3.0.9

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-invoke-app you can try this library

Comment: Thank You @HarishJangra , let me try this library now.

Comment: not working even then!

Answer (score 0):

change in library RNInvokeApp class

```
activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

adding to AndroidManifest for MainActivity:

```
android:showWhenLocked="true"
android:turnScreenOn="true"
```